# Get Statewise Location report from Google Ads

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ad-manager, google-ads-script

I want to get the report as shown here https://prnt.sc/oG7ms7tOdVfH

The input is Country = USA
Date from and Date to

But this gives non US states and it doesnt summarize the resuly by state names (not the state IDs)

Can anyone help me to get the REST API?

```
  curl "https://googleads.googleapis.com/v10/customers/${CUSTOMER_ID}/googleAds:searchStream" \ 
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \ --header "developer-token: ${DEVELOPER_TOKEN}" \ 
  --header "login-customer-id: ${MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID}" \ 
  --header "Authorization: Bearer ${OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN}" \ 
  --data '{ "query": "

      SELECT
        PERFORMANCE COST
      FROM LOCATION
      WHERE
COUNTRY = 'USA' AND 
         segments.date BETWEEN 20220101 AND 20220430
  
  " }'
```